# How can i make xsl count output aa,bb,cc,instead of aa,ab,ac,?

Tags: xslt

I am stuck with an issue when using xsl number count format a it works up to z perfectly after that i need the sequence to be aa,bb,cc... 
Instead it's aa,ab,ac.. i tried  format aa got the same result.

```
<xsl:variable name="name1">
  <xsl:number count="*" format="a"/> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="name">
  <xsl:number count="*" format="aa"/> 
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? And what should come after "zz"? Is it "aaa"?

Comment: its xslt 2.0. About after zz didnt think it since i have no need to go that far for now, but i guess aaa would be the proper way to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a format token you could use in `xsl:number` to get that type of output.

There may be a shorter way, but here's something I came up with quickly:

```
<xsl:variable name="i">
    <xsl:number count="*" /> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="0 to ($i - 1) idiv 26">
    <xsl:number value="($i - 1) mod 26 + 1" format="a"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

Depending on what exactly you're counting, you might be able to simplify this to:

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position() - 1"/>

<xsl:for-each select="0 to $i idiv 26">
    <xsl:number value="$i mod 26 + 1" format="a"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The second skips a couple of letters thats probably because of the way my xml is formated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to set  twice:

```
<fo:block letter-spacing="0.2pt">
    <xsl:number level="single" count="list-item" format="a"/>
    <xsl:number level="single" count="list-item" format="a"/>
</fo:block>
```

It is very simple but it seems working.